# Derivation of an uncertainty principle from the symplectic non-squeezing theorem

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, harmonic-analysis

Is there a derivation of an uncertainty principle or uncertainty-type principle from the symplectic non-squeezing theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. see:The symplectic camel and phase space quantization, by Maurice De Gosson.
 Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General, Volume 34, Number 47